# Which electrical plugs are used in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, electronic-items, power

I'm living in the Netherlands. I'm going on a holiday to Thailand. I need to know which electrical plug is used over there?

A European one? or like the one in the States? or something else?

Comment: http://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/thailand/

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, it's a valid question, but perhaps they're concerned you didn't try searching google for it...

Comment: @pnuts Yes you are 100 % right. Because I was in the holiday mood I didn't do my research. Forgive me for it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I spent quite some time in various places around Thailand (both major cities and small villages) and have mainly seen Type A sockets. I'm pretty confident that wherever you're going on your holiday, the accommodation will be fitted with Type C sockets - in other the words: the same as in the Netherlands. I wouldn't worry about getting an adapter. Also, in the very unlikely case you will need one, they'll be readily available pretty much everywhere (and much cheaper than in NL too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to Mark's post, you will likely not need an adapter coming from the Netherlands.

Thailand uses both the round pin plugs common in Europe as well as the flat pin plugs common in the USA & Canada.  The wall outlets here accommodate both style plugs, using sockets similar to the one shown in pnuts comment link - http://www.thailandguru.com/electricity-220volts-thailand.html

However, grounded sockets like the one shown on the thailandguru page are not common, a fair majority of outlets are ungrounded. If your devices use a grounded plug, then you may need a three pin to two pin cheater plug.  But otherwise your devices will plug in just fine.

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia has an article on all plugs used in all countries, with a table for comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country).

Or for a picture version (albeit comparing them to Australian plugs, but at least it shows you) - [this will show you what they look like](http://whatplug.info/from/australia/to/thailand).

Basically, international outlet/plug types A and C, and they run at 220V/50Hz.

Coming from the Netherlands, you will need an adaptor.

Comment: From my experience I didn't an adaptor in Thailand (I'm from Germany, same power plug as in The Netherlands)